# Dealing with microcontroller data over time

Tags: python, arduino

I'm working on a project involving Arduino and Python. Basically, I'm receiving data from sensors and using Python to write them to the database.

At the moment I have programmed Arduino in a way, that it's sending data every minute. A Python program is waiting for the data and inserts it.

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
while 1:
ser.open()
if ser.readline() != "":
    db.data.insert({"Light" : ser.readline(), "Ts" : time()})
ser.close()
```

This method has proved to be not so good, because instead of every minute, I get insert approximately once every 4 minutes.

So, what would be your advice for dealing with this? Program Arduino to output data all the time (less amount of work on computer processor), and then just wait in Python for another pick?

Comment: I think we need to see the arduino side of the code to understand why you are getting 4 minutes instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your Arduino code sends everything twice, half of the problem is that you call `ser.readline()` twice per iteration. This means that there'll be one insert per two messages.

Another thing that looks odd is that you open and close the serial port during each iteration. I doubt this is contibuting to your problem, but why not open the port just once, in the beginning?

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
ser.open()
while 1:
  line = ser.readline()
  if line != "":
    db.data.insert({"Light" : line, "Ts" : time()})
ser.close()
```

For further help, please post the Arduino code.

Comment: For some reason I believed that serial cannot be open all the time. Thank you, this works!